# replace for in with regular for loop with objects

Tags: javascript, loops, oop, object, for-loop

I'm currently trying to replace a for in loop that I have with a regular for loop out of curiosity, but with no success. I always get `undefined`. Is this even possible with javascript objects?

example object I loop over:

```
var el = {
    1: {type: "fish", commonName: "clownfish", scientificName: "sdasd", gender: "m", price: 1.99},
    2: {type: "fish", commonName: "dragonfish", scientificName: "dada", gender: "f", price: 2.99}
};
```

My working for in approach:

```
for (var element in el) {
   if (el[element].type === type && el.hasOwnProperty(element)) {
       elementNum++;
   }
}
```

The simple for loop approach that always gets me `Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`:

```
for(var i = 0, x = Object.keys(el).length; i < x; i++) {
   if (el[i].type === type && el.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      elementNum++;
   }
}
```

Comment: @Matias has the right answer, but I'm wondering why you aren't using an array? Are some indexes going to be skipped or something? Also, switch the order of `(el[i].type === type && el.hasOwnProperty(i))`  so that it doesn't check for `.type` if `el[i]` doesn't exist (because javascript stops looking through the `if AND` statement if it finds one that is false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're starting your loop from `0` while your first key in the whole object is `1`.

```js
var el = {
  1: {
    type: "fish",
    commonName: "clownfish",
    scientificName: "sdasd",
    gender: "m",
    price: 1.99
  },
  2: {
    type: "fish",
    commonName: "dragonfish",
    scientificName: "dada",
    gender: "f",
    price: 2.99
  }
};

var keyLength = Object.keys(el).length;

// I've simplified the for loop
for (var i = 1; i <= keyLength; i++) {
  console.log(el[i].commonName);
}
```

Comment: The answer cannot be shorter. Nice!

Comment: dammit, how could I not see this.. Thank you!!

Comment: @Sebsemillia I would consider that sometimes my mind is like a language hint tool (JSHint, JSLint...) lol

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer hehe ^^

Comment: Are there any benefits to this approach versus the original `for (var element in el) {` method?

Comment: @rorymorris89 I doubt it... Mostly, readability goes over efficiency for me. If `for..in` or `for..of` aren't the bottleneck in your app, I would say that they're better because they increase readability, aren't they?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I thought that declaring the x variable (in your answer the keyLength variable) in the for loop statement is better performance wise, since it saves one variable declaration if it is comma separated after the i variable. Am I wrong?

Comment: @TânNguyễn Thanks!

Comment: @Sebsemillia Meh, they're both variable declarations and unless you use `let` instead of `var`, they're both declared in the same scope because `for` doesn't create an inner scope... And I wouldn't mind about these micro-optimizations (if they exist at all...)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer ah ok, thank you for your opinion!

Comment: @Sebsemillia In fact, it was my fault refactoring the `for` loop, because I didn't notice you were declaring both variables there... My first look was wrong, I thought there were syntax errors... BTW, I would vote for more readability... Don't you think that declaring the `keyLenght` (or `x`) looks better if you do it before the whole `for` loop and you leave the loop with the simplest form possible? BTW, it's 100% subjective :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer definitely better for readability, no argument there. I'm just making some performance tests and this was one change besides others (e.g. trying for loop instead of for in loop).. ;)

Comment: @rorymorris89 oh yeah! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to iterate directly over the keys of the object.

```js
function getCount(type) {
    return Object.keys(el).reduce(function (r, k) {
        return r + +(el[k].type === type);
    }, 0);
}

var el = { 1: { type: "fish", commonName: "clownfish", scientificName: "sdasd", gender: "m", price: 1.99 }, 2: { type: "fish", commonName: "dragonfish", scientificName: "dada", gender: "f", price: 2.99 } };

console.log(getCount('fish'));
```

Comment: yes, I know this approach as well. I just wanted to try to do it with a simple for loop.. ;) thank you for your answer!

Comment: it works only if the object is in a fixed notation for the keys, like indices.